# Xamarin Forms animation limitation?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms if you want to create animations quickly you can call any of the animation extension methods such as TranslateTo(x, y), etc according to:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple/

But they don't seem to cover everything. For example on the above link, I don't see:

- A method to animate the background color?
- A parameter to specify the easing factor?

What are the other animation limitations in Xamarin Forms API, compared to the full iOS and Android animation capabilities?

Comment: Easing function is there, but not "easing factor".
Also in the documentation link I posted there is no background color in the list of methods.

Answer (score 0):

The "simple" ones are just the easy extension methods to do basic things. If you want the full control you need to use the animation class. There is even a background colour example a few pages below yours:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/custom/

Comment: Thanks, but my main question is, what kind of things can you do with the standard iOS and Android, which you cannot do with the Xamarin Forms animation API?